# Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error. source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I'm continuous getting this error. I have searched many articles but failed to get the solution. Please help me

```
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 7):

Temporary solution: if you ever came a cross such error then do this

**Step 1**: locate folder called "resolve-url-loader" inside "node_modules".

**Step 2**: open up the folder and look for "index.js". And open up that file.

**Step 3**: Inside "index.js", look for "var option".

example:

```
var options = Object.assign(
    {
      sourceMap: loader.sourceMap,
      engine   : 'postcss',
      silent   : false,
      absolute : false,
      keepQuery: false,
      removeCR : false,
      root     : false,
      debug    : false,
      join     : joinFn.defaultJoin
    },
```

**Step 4**: Look for `removeCR` which is turned `false`. Turn it to `true` and save the changes.

**Step 5**: restart your app either by `yarn start` or `npm start`. Error will be gone.

Note: do this every time whenever you came across such an error.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading resolve-url-loader to `^2.3.1` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: (No pun intended.)